# Multiple spaces overflowing textarea in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Enter multiple spaces and after a point of time it breaks into newline in IE but it overflows text area in Chrome
</textarea>
```

When entering multiple spaces inside text area in IE/EDGE after a particular point it breaks into new line .

But in Chrome/Firefox the multiple spaces inside textarea overflows the textarea instead of breaking into newline. I also tried by using white-space:pre but it creates horizontal scrollbar.I don't want scrolls inside my text area . 
Is there any CSS property to stop overflowing textarea.
Kindly help me to preserve whitespace inside text area in Chrome /Firefox also.
This is the html code for textarea component

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is the way the Browser Vendor chooses to display the `textareaElement.value`, it does not affect the value itself... Just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Would simply setting overflow: hidden; within the textareas CSS work?

Failing that you could break the text onto multiple lines with word-wrap: break-word;

Other people have fixed the issue by using white-space: pre-wrap;

They have also mentioned trying word-wrap: break-all;

I would also try placing the textarea inside a container div. Then setting the container to the size you would like, then make your text area width: 100%;

Just for general knowledge too, "& n b s p;" (minus the spaces) will be the equivalent of a space.
* Aware this doesn't really apply as you're using users input.

Hope these work out for you!

Thanks, J.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jason I have tried using overflow:hidden and word-wrap properties it works when giving some string characters as input but while giving spaces as input the cursor remains in same line and I want it to break in newline.I have also attached the html code.Kindly refer it.